# Can DotNetNuke be used with a reverse proxy?

Tags: dotnetnuke, reverse-proxy

Can DotNetNuke be used with a reverse proxy server?

Reverse Proxy: A proxy server that appears to the client as if it is an origin server. This is useful to hide the real origin server from the client for security reasons, or to load balance (taken from Google's definition of the term).

Basically DNN will respond to a request using the same portal alias that the request was made on. What I need to do is tell DNN to always respond to a request with a specific domain name only, regardless of the domain name that the request contained.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or if it is possible to turn this effect off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: Yes! but you have to disable friendly urls.

Comment: Could you expand on the steps involved in your solution? And what proxy are you using?